# Replace in Python-* equivalent?

Tags: python, replace

If I am finding & replacing some text how can I get it to replace some text that will change each day so ie anything between (( & )) whatever it is?

Cheers!

Comment: EDIT-So I have a string & I am replacing some characters with replace.().  Yet sometimes the text I want to replace changes-how can I specify to replace it whatever is, say, within the brackets?

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to use . but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Could You please paste the code and some example input?

Comment: If you're talking something in the spirit of wildcards, shylent's answer is spot on: regular expressions are the way to do it.

Comment: @Sam Stern: Please do not comment on your question.  Please EDIT your question to contain all the information.  And then delete the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Use regular expressions (http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)?

Could you please be more specific, I don't think I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish.

EDIT:

Ok, now I see. This may be done even easier, but here goes:

```
>>> import re

>>> s = "foo(bar)whatever"
>>> r = re.compile(r"(\()(.+?)(\))")
>>> r.sub(r"\1baz\3",s)
'foo(baz)whatever'
```

For multiple levels of parentheses this will not work, or rather it WILL work, but will do something you probably don't want it to do.

Oh hey, as a bonus here's the same regular expression, only now it will replace the string in the innermost parentheses:

```
r1 = re.compile(r"(\()([^)^(]+?)(\))")
```

Comment: One of this days I'm going to have to make myself learn about regex... I hate it when others can, with a few characters of nonsense, achieve what would take several lines of code for me...